# Detect mobile device and redirect only specific URLs

Tags: theming, proxies, acquia-dev-desktop

We are using [Acquia Mobile Redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/acquia_mobile_redirect) module to detect mobile device and redirect accordingly and it's working correctly on Acquia cloud. Its redirecting every request on mobile device.

But the request is to redirect only main domain not all the URLs.

For Example : when user entered www.example.com, then user should redirect to m.example.com and if user entered www.example.com/blog then don't redirect.

Question:

- Is this can be done at Varnish/LBS level?
- Is there any other module which support this kind on functionality?